# Display google column chart vAxis interval as whole number and intervals like 0,50,100,200,300

Tags: google-visualization

```
Wan to display the google column chart vAxis as whole number..
```

it is automatically displays 0.0,0.5,1.0... like this. I don't the max number of vAxis.

I have used the below code for whole number. need the solution like 0,1,2,3,4....

```
chart.draw(data, {
               width: 800,
               height: 480,
               orientation: 'horizontal',
               vAxis: {format: '0'}
              }
       );
```

give me some idea for solve this.. thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Visualisation - column chart interval issue (duplicate intervals)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168520/google-visualisation-column-chart-interval-issue-duplicate-intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify it via [`hAxis.ticks` property](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart):

> Replaces the automatically generated X-axis ticks with the specified
>   array. Each element of the array should be either a valid tick value
>   (such as a number, date, datetime, or timeofday), or an object. If
>   it's an object, it should have a v property for the tick value, and an
>   optional f property containing the literal string to be displayed as
>   the label.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> hAxis: { ticks: [5,10,15,20] }
> hAxis: { ticks: [{v:32, f:'thirty two'}, {v:64, f:'sixty four'}] }
> hAxis: { ticks: [new Date(2014,3,15), new Date(2013,5,15)] }
> hAxis: { ticks: [16, {v:32, f:'thirty two'}, {v:64, f:'sixty four'}, 128] }
> ```
>
> This option is only supported for a continuous axis.
>
> Type: Array of elements Default: auto

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 0.1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 0.5],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 1.3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 8.4],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 6.5],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 0.6],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 2.7],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 1.2],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 2.9],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 1.0],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 0-10)',
          minValue: 0,
          ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        },
        orientation: 'horizontal'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="height: 480px"></div>
```

Comment: one more doubt... if doesn't set vAxis .. it will shows like  0.0, 0.5, 1.0.. have to display only integer...

Comment: If vAxis.ticks is not specified, ticks  will be generated automatically and in my example displayed as 0, 2.5, 5.0.. So, `ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` should do the trick